# jQuery live search which shows every occurrence with search input

Tags: jquery

I managed to implement basic search. This is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#VetSearch').keyup(function(){
         var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $('#vetResults li').each(function(){
           var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
              (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();            
         });
        });
      });
```

This is HTML:

```
<ol id="groomerResults">
<li style="display: list-item;">Some name, Zagreb</li>
<li style="display: list-item;">Some name, Zagreb</li>
<li style="display: list-item;">Some name, Zagreb</li>
<li style="display: list-item;">Some name, Zagreb</li>
</ol>
```

This list is generated in code... But it doesn't matter for my problem.

I can only search by first characters but I want to be able to search every word. For example if I search "Zagreb" it should show all result with Zagreb in it.

How can I do that?

Comment: You're explicitly checking for 'starts with' by testing the index `== 0`. Does making that `>= 0` fix it? But there must be plenty of implementations of this out there already you can just use.

Comment: Your simple fix is the answer! Thanks a bunch!